# Invalid JSON data error in composer rest server

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am new to hyperledger. I am getting an error in composer rest server when I am making a post request.
 I am putting this in the request

```
{
  "$class": "org.example.biznet.SampleAsset",
  "assetId": "string",
  "owner": {},
  "value": "string"
}
```

and my cto file is 
namespace org.example.biznet

```
participant SampleParticipant identified by participantId {
  o String participantId
  o String firstName
  o String lastName
}

asset SampleAsset identified by assetId {
  o String assetId
  --> SampleParticipant owner
  o String value
}

transaction SampleTransaction {
  --> SampleAsset asset
  o String newValue
}

event SampleEvent {
  --> SampleAsset asset
  o String oldValue
  o String newValue
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using the example JSON, but unfortunately there is an error with it.

The **owner** property you have in the SampleAsset is a relationship, but it just needs to be represented as a string.  In the post request you can just specify the ID of an owner e.g. `"owner" : "7465",` or you can specify the whole relationship string `"owner" : "resource:org.example.biznet.SampleParticipant#7465",`

**Note:** that whatever you put in the owner field, the relationship will NOT be checked or resolved by Composer.

Answer (score 0):

just simple @ajay Singh

You have to replace {} with `resource:org.example.biznet.SampleParticipant#participantId` in "owner" key field.

every time if you provide a relationship in any asset like `--> SampleParticipant owner` then you need to provide that relationship owner as I mentioned above.

now, try to understand `resource:org.example.biznet.SampleParticipant#participantId`

org.example.biznet -> it is name space of your cto file.

SampleParticipant -> it is possible that your cto file has more than one type of participant in your case there is only one type of participant that is SampleParticipant.

'#' -> it is compulsory to add # between participant type and participant id.

participantId -> unique id that you give the time of creating the SampleParticipant.

In simple, this all things describe that SampleAsset with assetId 001 is owned by SampleParticipant that have participantId 01.